# eclipse not starting, gtk warning

Tags: java, eclipse, gtk3

my eclipse installation stopped working recently. It seems to start normal, but after the splashscreen, the window doesnt appear. If i run eclipse in the terminal, it seems to be something with gtk wrong:

```
(eclipse:10305): Gtk-WARNING **: 08:26:20.017: Failed to parse /home/simon/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini:  The key value file does not contain the group »Settings«

(java:10329): Gtk-WARNING **: 08:26:20.861: Failed to parse /home/simon/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini:  The key value file does not contain the group »Settings«
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Logback config file: /home/simon/Dokumente/Projekte-Software/Projekte-Schule/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration/logback.1.15.0.20191217-1149.xml
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Initializing logback
Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.wizards.MarketplaceDropAdapter$2
```

I opened the gtk config file and it is completely empty

Comment: Is this a problem with an updated GTK but an outdated Eclipse? Which Eclipse and GTK version do you have? Can you reproduce this issue with the current version of Eclipse (2020-03)?

Comment: After some resarch it seems to be an gtk problem. I recently updatet to fedora 32, and it seems to be that the theme settings arent saved in the settings file any more